# The best way to convert a String to an Integer or Natural in Idris

Tags: string, integer, type-conversion, idris

What is the **best way to convert a String to an Integer or Natural in Idris**?

I know the standard library is still a work in progress and so if the answer is I should add it to the standard library then that's fine I will try and do that, but before I thought I would confirm there isn't already a way.

The **best I could come up with** is this if I want to read an Index from the user:

```
indexAsString <- getLine
let indexAsInt : Integer = cast indexAsString
let items: Vect _ _ = ["shoe", "bat", "hat"]
let i = integerToFin indexAsInt $ length items
maybe (print "invalid index") (\ii => print $ index ii items) i
```

But this way, I get **no indication of failure from cast**. Not only is the fact that indexAsString might not be in format allowing it to be converted to an Integer, but on top of that it **doesn't even fail at runtime, producing 0 as a result of a "bad cast"**.

Please tell me there is a better way and/or point me in the right direction.

As a side note, is there a particular reason there is no Read typeclass in Idris? Or has it just not made it in yet?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Idris has a `parseInteger` and `parsePositive` function in `Data.String` with the type signatures

```
Num a => Neg a => String -> Maybe a
```

and

```
Num a => String -> Maybe a
```

http://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/base_doc/docs/Data.String.html

Comment: That's new! but today it is the appropriate answer so let's try and upvote it to the top. To be fair though, probably a whole lot less people will have this question now.

Comment: Yeah, it got added in 0.9.20 by the looks of it. It isn't that easy to find though; I looked through the whole prelude a few days ago and didn't find it, thinking it would be in something like `Prelude.Strings`.

Answer (score 4):

I may mistake but I try to share what I think about it. **indication of failure** is about parsing.

In old idris repository I can see `readInt` which is `String -> Maybe Int` but I don't know where is it now.

Howerver there is custom implementation I found [here](https://github.com/david-christiansen/idris-type-providers/blob/master/Providers/Silly.idr):

```
charToInt : Char -> Maybe Int
charToInt c = let i = cast {to=Int} c in
              let zero = cast {to=Int} '0' in
              let nine = cast {to=Int} '9' in
              if i < zero || i > nine
                then Nothing
                else Just (i - zero)

total
parse' : Int -> List Int -> Maybe Int
parse' _   []      = Nothing
parse' acc [d]     = Just (10 * acc + d)
parse' acc (d::ds) = parse' (10 * acc + d) ds


total parseInt : String -> Maybe Int
parseInt str = (sequence (map charToInt (unpack str))) >>= parse' 0

main : IO ()
main = do let r = parseInt !getLine
          putStrLn "."
```

It's easy to read how does it work. `charToInt` (probably I think it could be coded better but I don't know how) is based on `cast` , `parse` is processing Integers one by one recursive doing `*10` for each new Integer from List (e.g. symbol) and `parseInt` maps unpacked `String` with `charToInt` and getting the result passing it to `parse`. `!` is alike `=<<` in Haskell.

Comment: Thx for taking the time to answer! I would have preferred an answer involving some function in the standard library. Now I am left wondering why this is not part of it in some shape or form and how I should approach making a PR to get the Read typeclass or something like that in Idris.